# Sending contact form results in "unexpected error"

Tags: php, forms, send, contacts

Working on a project.. Ac-photography.net

Need help with contact form. It doesnt seem to send and i keep getting "unexpected error message"

```
<div class="contact_form">
            <div class="done">
                    <b>Thank you!</b> I have received your message. 
                </div>

                <form method="post" action="process.php">
                    <p>name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="text" />

                    <p>email</p>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="text" id="email" />

                    <p>message</p>
                    <textarea name="comment" class="text textarea"></textarea>

                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="send" class="submit-button" />
                </form>
```

Not sure how to put up the PHP on here.

**Any help is appreciated. Thank you.**

```
    <?php

    //Retrieve form data. 
    //GET - user submitted data using AJAX
    //POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
    $name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
    $email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
    $comment = ($_GET['comment']) ?$_GET['comment'] : $_POST['comment'];

    //flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
    if ($_POST) $post=1;

    //Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
    if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
    if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
    if (!$comment) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your comment.'; 

    //if the errors array is empty, send the mail
    if (!$errors) {

//recipient
$to = 'Your Name <alex.cherkasov@gmail.com>';    // <--------- change your email here
//sender
$from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

//subject and the html message
$subject = 'Message from ' . $name; 
$message = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message</td><td>' . nl2br($comment) . '</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

//send the mail
$result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

//if POST was used, display the message straight away
if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
    else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

//else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
//ajax script can react accordingly
//1 means success, 0 means failed
} else {
    echo $result;   
}

    //if the errors array has values
    } else {
//display the errors message
for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
echo '<a href="form.php">Back</a>';
exit;
    }


    //Simple mail function with HTML header
    function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($result) return 1;
else return 0;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: post it like this HTML that you posted!

Comment: You have a semantic problem on the side: replace `$(‘a[href*=#]‘).click(function() {` with this `$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {`. But that is not causing the error.

Comment: If added a new answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### JavaScript part

The form is not processed correctly because it doesn't get any value. Take a look at **contact-form.js**.

You're building the `data` variable:

```
var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&website=' + website.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());
```

But than in the AJAX call you pass a string with the value `data`:

```
//pass the data
data: "data",
```

Try this instead:

```
//pass the data
data: data,
```

---

#### PHP part (process.php)

When I simply call the script like this:

> http://ac-photography.net/process.php?email=test@test.com&name=name&comment=comment

I'll get a warning:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 > invalid address in D:\Hosting\6405740\html\process.php on line 72

Fix this and check whether the mail was send correctly. It will than return `1` as expected.

Comment: i replaced the "data" to data but it still give me the same error.

Comment: I put the PHP up. PLEASE HELP :)

Comment: Hey, i got the the result to come back as one, but the emails to arrive in my Gmail. It seems to work on the website now, but still not email Thank you for your help so far